# Convert ip route add to netplan state

Tags: networking, netplan, routing

I am confused a bit about the following command
(we had it in ubuntu 14 /etc/network/interfaces file)

up ip route add local fc00::x:x:x/126 dev bond0

What does 'local' means here, and how do i translate it to netplan state in ubuntu 18 ?

`bonds:
  bonds0:
    routes:
    - to: fc00::x:x:x/126
      scope: link`

Or it should be different ?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the embedded colons, the address fc00::x:x:x/126 must be quoted:

```
bonds:
  bonds0:
    routes:
    - to: "fc00::x:x:x/126"
      scope: link
```

Comment: I have checked: it works without quotes. I am just wondering if the whole idea is correct:
- to DEST
  scope: link